# iOS add a custom view to UINavigationBar like Viber app

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to add a subview (a segment control) like Viber app main screen.
I tried setting self.navigationItem.titleView = myCustomView, but it seems to not working
How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding this code from a UIViewController inside a UINavigationController,  this code should work. So You need to check some points:

- This view controller is part of the navigation controller?
- The navigation bar is part of the navigation controller?
- Are you initializing `myCustomView` correctly? Is it non-nil when you do this?
- Is this view controller in the top of the stack? As written in the docs, and you can see that according to what you see from apps in general, this titleView is *only used when item is topmost on the stack*.

Try to NSLog the following to check some of them:

```
NSLog(@"self.navigationItem exists? %d", self.navigationItem != nil);
NSLog(@"customView exists? %d", customView != nil);
```